# Big O - for loop increment by partial N

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

```c++
void function(int N){
  int c=0;
  for (int i =0; i< N; i+= N/5)
      c++;
}
```

What is the Big O of the above? Since for every N the loop would iterate 5 times, would it be O(1)?

Comment: Yes, I think so.. it will be constant i.e. `O(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for example that `N = 100`. Let's draw a table:

```
Iteration |   i
----------+------
    0     |  20
    1     |  40            
    2     |  60
    3     |  80
    4     |  100
```

Note that it doesn't matter what value of `N` you pick, the number of iteration will be at most 5.
So we conclude that `i` **doesn't** depend on `N`.

So.. you're right, it's `O(1)`.

---

### Clarification

What's the difference between the above example and the loop: `for(i=0;i<N;i+=20)`?

If you draw the table, you'll get the same table! But, in this case, the result **do** depends on the value of `N`. If you pick `N = 200` you'll get more than 5. So the result in this case will be `O(N)`.

Comment: I don’t understand your reasoning (in fact, I think it’s wrong). Why does the table show us what you purport it shows? You could draw the same table for `for(i=0;i<N;i+=20)` and it would look identical, yet here the runtime is O(N).

Comment: You are (very) right, thanks for pointing on that. I didn't notice that I didn't explain it well. Edited, I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 1):

> Since for every N the loop would iterate 5 times, would it be O(1)?

Precisely. The running time only depends on a constant – 5 – so it’s bounded by O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the result is not depended upon N.

Answer (score 0):

A formal to answer your question is like the following:

[image]